# Read in only rows in between certain strings Python

Tags: python, csv

So I have a text file that I am trying to read with csv in python, however I only want the rows in between two rows that start with certain strings. I have no problems with just reading the data, I have:

```
import csv
with open('path to file','r') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=" ")
```

and to get all the data I can just loop through and append to a list:

```
raw_data=[]
for row in reader:
    raw_data.append(row)
```

I know I can get the rows I want by doing something like:

```
for row in raw_data:
    if row[0] == 'string1':
        begin_idx = raw_data.index(row)
    elif row[0] == 'string2':
        end_idx = raw_data.index(row)
data=[]
for idx in range(begin_idx+1,end_idx):
    data.append(raw_data[idx])
```

However, I was hoping to be able to do this all at once when I first loop through the text file, so if anyone has any ideas on how this could be done it would appreciated.

Note, the reason I am not just looking for index of the rows I want is because they are just a list of integers that will change each time I run this. The pdf to text conversion I run isn't extremely clean, so the row titles don't line up with the actual data for the row.

Comment: *Aside*: Your 2nd code snippet could equivalently be: `raw_data = list(reader)`.

Comment: You could also do `data = raw_data[begin_idx + 1, end_idx]`  instead of the last loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterator objects are nice in that they are just calling `next()` on the object like `reader` when using `in`
So this will allow you to go through this in one linear pass by looping through separately when you hit the starting string. Try this:

```
import csv
with open('path to file','r') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=" ")

data=[]
for row in reader:
    if row[0] == 'string1':
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]=='string2':
                break
            data.append(row)
```

Comment: This is in line with what I was thinking to do, but just could not figure out how to implement it, thank you.

Comment: No problem! And as a note, normally I'd be against re-using/overwriting a variable name like `row`, but I think it's appropriate here

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a state variable into your `for` loop:

```
data = []
copying = False
for row in reader:
    if copying:
        data.append(row)
    if row[0] == 'string1':
        copying = True
    if row[0] == 'string2':
        copying = False
```

Comment: You could also `break` the loop instead of setting `copying` back to `False`, although this only works if `string2` never occurs before `string1`. And if I'm not mistaken, `string2` shouldn't be in `data` so you need to move the last condition to the top.

Comment: @xZise yes I didn't want `string2` in `data`, and it does work to move the last condition to the beginning.